# prove of disprove the modified shannon's theorem when the correctness requirement is relaxed

Tags: encryption, perfect-secrecy

Suppose the correctness requirement of private-key encryption scheme is now relaxed to require only that
$$
\Pr[Dec_k(Enc_k(m)) = m] \ge \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon.
$$
Prove of disprove that if an encryption scheme satisfies the perfect secrecy and the relaxed correctness, then $|M| \le 2|K|$, where $M, K$ are the message space and the key space, respectively.

---

The following is my thinking. Assume $|M| > 2|K|$. For fixed $c \in M$, define $p(m) = \sum_{k \in K} \Pr[Dec_k(c) = m]$. Since $\sum_{m \in M} p(m) = |K| < \frac{1}{2}|M|$, there exists $m_0 \in M$ such that $p(m_0) < \frac{1}{2}$. I want to show that $\Pr[Enc_k(m_0) = c]$ is small and find $\Pr[Enc_k(m_0) = c] \ne \Pr[Enc_k(m_1) = c]$ for some $m_1$ which contradicts with perfect secrecy, but I failed.

Tanks for any help.